# can spark-submit be used as a job scheduler?

Tags: spark-submit

I have a spark standalone cluster with no other job scheduler installed. I wonder if `spark-submit` can be used as a job scheduler for both spark and non-spark jobs (e.g. a scala jar not written for Spark and not using RDD)?

Based on my testing, `spark-submit` be used to submit non-Spark jobs and the jobs run successfully. But here are my questions:

1. Are the the following options still meaningful?

   `--driver-cores
   --driver-memory
   --executor-memory
   --total-executor-cores`
2. If No to 1, does it mean `spark-submit` can maintain a queue of spark and non-spark jobs using FIFO but it does not manage the resource of the non-spark job?
3. If 2 is true, should I use another scheduler, e.g. SGE or LSF, to submit non-spark jobs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out after many testings. Yes, spark standalone can be a job scheduler for both spark and non-spark jobs.

1. However, for non-spark jobs, `spark-submit` only creates drivers, no executors.
2. The jobs are scheduled in a FIFO queue, and jobs at the head of the queue get started only when its resource requirement, e.g. cores and memory specified in the `spark-submit` command, are met.